# fetch data inmultidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've got a problem.

I have got this array:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [id] => 1 
        [opt] => reg_limit
        [value] => 0 
      ) 
    [1] => Array ( 
        [id] => 3 
        [opt] => pages_offline 
        [value] => [] 
       ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [id] => 4 
        [opt] => devolp 
        [value] => TRUE 
       ) 
)
```

I want to check if the [opt] devolp has the [value] TRUE in the third array. How can I do?

Comment: -1 for "Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved".

Comment: -1 no evidence of attempting to code this yourself. Reading docs on PHP arrays would have the answer to such simple problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
$aArray = Array ( 
[0] => Array ( 
    [id] => 1 
    [opt] => reg_limit
    [value] => 0 
  ) 
[1] => Array ( 
    [id] => 3 
    [opt] => pages_offline 
    [value] => [] 
   ) 
[2] => Array ( 
    [id] => 4 
    [opt] => devolp 
    [value] => TRUE 
   ) 
)

foreach($aArray AS $aInnerArray){
  if($aInnerArray['opt'] == 'devolp' && $aInnerArray['value'] == TRUE){
     //YOUR USE CASE
  }
}
```

Comment: As far as I understand, the OP only needs to check the third item (index 2) ==> no loops needed in this case.

Comment: Maybe, The question is really poorly described

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($array[2]['value']) echo 'true';
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided you will work with a big array in the future and need some flexibility, this foreach will work for you:

```
foreach($array as $a) {
    if(array_key_exists("opt", $a) && $a['opt'] == "devolp") {
        if(array_key_exists("value", $a) && $a['value'] == TRUE) {
            echo "Found it!";
            //Do whatever you need to do here....
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need for loops in this case.

Comment: I see what you mean.  I initially misread the OP question.  That's what I get for being in a hurry.

Comment: Yeah, happens sometimes :)

Answer (score 0):

Since the OP's question is quite vague on the details wether or not he knows which array key he needs to check,

Here is a simple example that you can use if you **know** the array key that you need to check in.

```
$bool = $yourMultiDeminsionalArray[2]['value'];

if ($bool) {

    //Do some awesome PHP shizzle here

}
```